# What would be the right relationship? - Laravel

Tags: php, database, laravel

I'm trying to build a Territory Management System for a non-profit organization.

The point of the TMA is to assign territories to different users. 
A user can request to be assigned to a territory, and the SuperAdmin can either decline or confirm.

Each Territory has different types (Ex: Type A, Type B and Type C).
Each User also has different types (A, B or C)

A User can only view and request territories with the same type, and can only view and request territories that aren't currently assigned to another User.

(Ex: User with type A can view and request territories with type A).

### Database Schema:

```
territories
- id
- type_id
- name

users
- id
- type_id
- name

types
- id
- name

assignments
- id
- territory_id
- user_id
- status (enum: confirmed, declined, requested, canceled)
```

I've tried making the relationships but found that it wasn't simple. (or maybe I'm just not doing it right)

Should this be done with the query builder? If so, what's the right way of retrieving a list of available territories (have not been assigned) that corresponds to the Auth User type_id?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to retrieve all the assigned teriteri for the specific `type_id`, then need to find remaining teriteri from the territory table.

```
$user = Auth::user();
$same_type_users = DB::table('users')->where('type_id',$user->type_id)->pluck('id');

$all_assigned_teritory = DB::table('assignments')->where('user_id','IN',$same_type_users)->pluck('id');

$available_teritories= DB::table('territories')->where('id', 'NOT IN', $all_assigned_teritory)->where('type_id' , $user->type_id)->value('email');
```

Comment: Awesome! This makes sense. Just that $all_assigned_territories should have pluck('territory_id).

But isn't there a cleaner way of writing this in a model. Something like ```auth()->user()->available_territories```?

Answer (score 0):

You can go with eloquent.

If a user can have only 1 territory then it's 1 to 1
If a user can have many territories then its 1 to many.